# how to add images to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

Hi i found this code online, its for a memory game created in JavaScript,

I want to be able to put images in the array instead of the letters that are there, how do I do it?
 Thank You

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Here is the array .. var memory_array = ['A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D','E','E','F','F','G','G','H','H','I','I','J','J','K','K','L','L'];  Here is the link to the game code https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Memory-Game-Programming-Tutorial

Comment: Here is the link to the code https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Memory-Game-Programming-Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

you must add image source (src) to array, not images.
and if you want to change image , just change src.

```
  <img id="myImage" />
     <script>
         var x = new Array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg');
         var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
         img.setAttribute("src", x[0]);
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, did you look at the link I posted up, ? if so that the way you still do it?